# Install Anbox without snap (on debian or other distros)

Tags: linux, debian, android

Is there a description / tutorial how to install anbox without snap / snapd?

I am using a debian. And an unofficial deb repository with an deb package for anbox would be fine.
Or is there any useful description / link how to compile and run anbox without snap.

The official description for compilation uses at the end a command to create a snap package und install it per snap. But i want to test/run it without snap.

Please no discussion why i don't want using snap. I want my debian without snap thats it.

It would be really great if there are some tips/links/tutorials how to install anbox without snap.

Comment: It is now on the testing/unstable repos

Answer (score 2):

The `anbox` package is now available in the `contrib` APT repositories for Debian 11 Bullseye and even Debian 10 Buster, see https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/anbox. This is preferred over polluting your system with unstable (sid) packages.

1. Enable contrib repositories for APT, e.g. by editing
   `/etc/apt/sources.list` (see [serverfault.com answer](https://serverfault.com/a/240921)).
2. Refresh available packages using `apt update`.
3. Run `apt install anbox`.

Answer (score 0):

As the package is [available in the sid/testing repository](https://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/anbox/download), you could either download it from there and install it via `dpkg -i`, or use [apt-pinning](http://jaqque.sbih.org/kplug/apt-pinning.html) to have it managed via `apt`.